# Still Getting Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Can some one pls give your inputs

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, cucumber

I am getting the above error : Below is the xpath :

```
String MeetingTypedropdown = "//*[@id='meetingDatesForm:meetingDatesTable_data']/tr["+(i+1)+"]/td[3]//div[3]/span";
PageUtil.clickOnlink(driver, MeetingTypedropdown);
```

On clicking the dropdown getting invalid selector Exception....
Below is html:

```
<div class="ui-cell-editor-input">
<div id="meetingDatesForm:meetingDatesTable:6:j_idt310" class="ui-selectonemenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all widthLarge" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" aria-owns="meetingDatesForm:meetingDatesTable:6:j_idt310_items">
    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
        <input id="meetingDatesForm:meetingDatesTable:6:j_idt310_focus" name="meetingDatesForm:meetingDatesTable:6:j_idt310_focus" type="text" autocomplete="off" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-activedescendant="meetingDatesForm:meetingDatesTable:6:j_idt310_2" aria-describedby="meetingDatesForm:meetingDatesTable:6:j_idt310_2" aria-disabled="false">
        </div>

        <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
            <select id="meetingDatesForm:meetingDatesTable:6:j_idt310_input" name="meetingDatesForm:meetingDatesTable:6:j_idt310_input" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                <option value="" data-escape="true">Select one...</option>
                <option value="3" data-escape="true">Board</option>
                <option value="140" selected="selected" data-escape="true">Commission S</option>
                <option value="2" data-escape="true">Commission I</option>
                <option value="219" data-escape="true">Commission F</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <label id="meetingDatesForm:meetingDatesTable:6:j_idt310_label" class="ui-selectonemenu-label ui-inputfield ui-corner-all">Commission S</label>

//on selecting the dropdown button the below code gets hightlighted
        <div class="ui-selectonemenu-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-c"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can some one please help

***** Update*** html *** I also see this for the drop down selection and this tag gets highlighted

```
<div class="ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper" style="max-height:200px">
    <ul id="meetingDatesForm:meetingDatesTable:6:j_idt310_items" class="ui-selectonemenu-items ui-selectonemenu-list ui-widget-content ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="meetingDatesForm:meetingDatesTable:6:j_idt310_2">
        <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="Select one..." tabindex="-1" role="option" id="meetingDatesForm:meetingDatesTable:6:j_idt310_0">Select one...</li>
        <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="Board" tabindex="-1" role="option" id="meetingDatesForm:meetingDatesTable:6:j_idt310_1">Board</li>
        <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight" data-label="Commission S" tabindex="-1" role="option" id="meetingDatesForm:meetingDatesTable:6:j_idt310_2">Commission S</li>
        <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="Commission I" tabindex="-1" role="option" id="meetingDatesForm:meetingDatesTable:6:j_idt310_3">Commission I</li>
        <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="Commission F" tabindex="-1" role="option" id="meetingDatesForm:meetingDatesTable:6:j_idt310_4">Commission F</li>
```

Comment: please add the exception stack trace

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (sometimes I get this)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your selector looks valid , if the error is not visible use webdriver wait.

first scroll to that element:

```
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", dropdownelement);
```

then wait for the visibility:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, DURATION.second);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(yourlocator)));
```

**Update:**

your locator is wrong use select class as its a selct dropdown

```
Select objSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("id="meetingDatesForm:meetingDatesTable:6:j_idt310_input"")));
Select.selectByIndex(4);
```

Comment: let me try and revert

Comment: @sandy please accept the answer by clickign the tick sign if it helps

Comment: trying still not working

Comment: whats the error

Comment: same thing org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Comment: did it scrolll to that element ? is the  locator correct ?

Comment: iam doubting on the dropdownoption locator ..

Comment: use selct calss updated the answer

Comment: drop down comes under li class

Comment: Still having the same issue it is not selecting the value from the dropdown any more inputs will  be helpful